# How to retrieve custom meta term of category taxonomy from WP Rest API?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, rest-api, wp-api

First I added custom meta term called **Color** for Category taxonomy, see the code below

**Add new colorpicker field to "Add new Category" screen**

```
function colorpicker_field_add_new_category( $taxonomy ) {

  ?>

    <div class="form-field term-colorpicker-wrap">
        <label for="term-colorpicker">Category Color</label>
        <input name="_category_color" value="#ffffff" class="colorpicker" id="term-colorpicker" />
        <p>This is the field description where you can tell the user how the color is used in the theme.</p>
    </div>

  <?php

}
add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'colorpicker_field_add_new_category' );
```

**Add new colopicker field to "Edit Category" screen**

```
function colorpicker_field_edit_category( $term ) {

    $color = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, '_category_color', true );
    $color = ( ! empty( $color ) ) ? "#{$color}" : '#ffffff';

  ?>

    <tr class="form-field term-colorpicker-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><label for="term-colorpicker">Severity Color</label></th>
        <td>
            <input name="_category_color" value="<?php echo $color; ?>" class="colorpicker" id="term-colorpicker" />
            <p class="description">This is the field description where you can tell the user how the color is used in the theme.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>

  <?php


}
add_action( 'category_edit_form_fields', 'colorpicker_field_edit_category' );
```

**Term Metadata - Save Created and Edited Term Metadata**

```
function save_termmeta( $term_id ) {

    // Save term color if possible
    if( isset( $_POST['_category_color'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['_category_color'] ) ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, '_category_color', sanitize_hex_color_no_hash( $_POST['_category_color'] ) );
    } else {
        delete_term_meta( $term_id, '_category_color' );
    }

}
add_action( 'created_category', 'save_termmeta' );  // Variable Hook Name
add_action( 'edited_category',  'save_termmeta' );  // Variable Hook Name
```

**Enqueue colorpicker styles and scripts.**

```
function category_colorpicker_enqueue( $taxonomy ) {

    if( null !== ( $screen = get_current_screen() ) && 'edit-category' !== $screen->id ) {
        return;
    }

    // Colorpicker Scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker' );

    // Colorpicker Styles
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'category_colorpicker_enqueue' );
```

**Print javascript to initialize the colorpicker**

```
function colorpicker_init_inline() {
    if( null !== ( $screen = get_current_screen() ) && 'edit-category' !== $screen->id ) {
        return;
    }
  ?>
    <script>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
            $( '.colorpicker' ).wpColorPicker();
        } ); // End Document Ready JQuery
    </script>
  <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'colorpicker_init_inline', 20 );
```

Everything works great, here is the result

[image]

Now, when I visit `http://localhost/wp/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed` I can't see the new meta term listed, see the image below:

[image]

So, my question how can I retrieve the new meta term ? Do I miss something ?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462187/wordpress-rest-api-v2-how-to-list-taxonomy-terms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to tell WordPress to show this custom field in the API response:
`register_term_meta('category', '_category_color', ['show_in_rest' => true]);`

Then you can filter the category term API endpoint like so:

```
add_filter( 'rest_prepare_category',function($response, $item, $request){
    $color = get_term_meta( $item->term_id, '_category_color', true );
    $response->data['color'] = $color ?: '';
    return $response;
}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Works great +1
thanks